# Can't open ./scripts/ci.sh with github action

Tags: github-actions

My Rust repository containing multiple subfolders.I would like to be able to build and test each of the projects for each pull request or when a new code is pushed to the master. So I created a ci.sh. Performing the action, I get a "Can't open ./scripts/ci.sh" error.

I've checked that `ci.sh` has been added to the repo.

What's the proper way to designate `ci.sh`'s path?

```yaml
name: Rust

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

env:
  CARGO_TERM_COLOR: always

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build, test, clippy all
        # run: "${{ format('{0}/.github/scripts/ci.sh', github.workspace) }}" <-also can't find script
        run: sh ./scripts/ci.sh
```

Directory Structure:

```
MY_EXAMPLES
- .github
 - workflows
  - scripts
   - ci.sh
  - build.yml
- EXAMPLE_1
- EXAMPLE_2
- EXAMPLE_3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following and it worked.

```sh
echo hi > .github/workflows/scripts/ci.sh
```

```yaml
name: test
on: push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: test
        run: sh .github/workflows/scripts/ci.sh
```

[image]